# iOS In App Purchases rejection: Missing IAPs

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have submitted an iphone app with in-app purchase But my Binary is rejected and I have got the following message from Apple

From Apple. Missing IAPs

We are unable to complete the review of your app since one or more of your In App Purchases have not been submitted for review.

Please be sure to take action and submit your In App Purchases AND upload a new binary in iTunes Connect. Learn more about submitting In App Purchases for review in the iTunes Connect Developer Guide.

Once you've submitted your In App Purchases and uploaded a new binary, we can proceed with your review.

My questions is Should i create a new binary and upload it or can i resubmit the binary which the In App Purchase has been rejected ?

Answer (score 8):

looks like an old post but but making it more detailed because I myself faced it and made me searching multiple posts for actual steps.

First of all, you don't need to create a new binary because you just forgot to select In App purchases for review. Below are the steps how you can do this

Before making the Application "Ready to Upload" you need to select all the In App Purchases in Applicatin's Detail Page.

At iTunes Connect -> Click your application -> Click Edit -> scroll to bottom, you would see In App Purchase link, select the In Apps you want to make the part of your Application Submission Process. Once you are confirmed then change your product status to "Ready to Upload Binary"

If somehow you forgot to do that then there is only 1 way. Which is Reject and then Re Do the process I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

you missed to submit the in app purchases for review . Now each of your in app must have its status as " Waiting For Review " . You can submit your binary and related in app purchases to the apple review process . You should create a new binary and submit it to the app store review process.Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it's not clear for me, i have send the .ipa to my client and he has missed to submit the in app purchase. Kow should i create a new .ipa and resend it to my client or he can resubmit the old .ipa with the in app purchase "Waiting for review" ?? thanks

Comment: You can send a new build to your client so that the same can be submitted to the app store review.

Comment: I am  now facing this same problem and found this post. But in my iTunes Connect, I do not see the "-> Click Edit ->" part mentioned in the answer above by Ahsan.Amin. And I don't see either any place "to submit the in app purchase".

Answer (score 2):

Here is my case. All info is included in the reply to Apple.

```
Thanks very much for reviewing the app.

On IAP a few days before, 
our Product Manager did not know in-app purchase products subscription well . 
In order to get more free user, 
he sent three months subscription for free to new registered users
by adjusting member date on the server side.

After a lot of querying, 
we will use IAP App Store Promotions to get more free user, 
instead of changing the member date simply on the server side.

We have completed in-app purchases, 
and will upload a new binary in App Store Connect soon.
```

#### Subscription issue, not on the iOS client Side, but on the server side.

---

I replied. After a while, I see the place "to submit the in app purchase" in an iOS product on App Store once.

I handled, and it disappeared. Very interesting.

[image: 00]

[image: 111]

[image: 222]

I have not seen the place "to submit the in app purchase" in an iPad product on App Store.

---

### On App Store Reviewing Issue, honest communication is very important.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should create a new binary and upload it.

You should do what Apple told you to do.

---

This is my case.

Firstly, you should add meta info to IAP products.

The meta info, is an image with its description.

**Get it ready.**

[image: 00]

Then Apple will add **IAP Add Options** in the app version page, which is to be reviewed, after some time.

[image: 111]

[image: 222]

[image: 333]

Answer (score 0):

Six steps from Apple, [Workflow for configuring in-app purchases](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devb57be10e7)

- Sign a Paid Applications Agreement
- Configure in-app purchases in App Store Connect

I thought the In App Purchase link is here, which Ahsan.Amin means, iOS Version 13.2

[image: 000]

- Enable in-app purchase in Xcode
- Design and create your in-app purchase
- Test in-app purchases
- Publish your app and in-app purchase on the App Store

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to App Store Connect
2. Select Your App Rejected
3. Scroll Down and you see a section "In-App Purchases and Subscriptions" Next To Build.
4. Select your In-App purchase Itme
5. Submit the review

NOTE: Your In-App Purchases status should be Ready to Submit